# Should a Computer Science student learn FPGA

Tags: fpga, verilog

I'm a Computer Science student, I know CS is more about algorithms, Theory of computing, Data structures, Artificial intelligence, etc. But I think CS student must also have a basic understanding of Hardware design. Recently I'm taking VLSI course and I got some interest in Hardware design. So, I was thinking to learn about FGPA's so that I can have a more better understanding of hardware. Can anybody guide me here ... Should I learn or it is for students belonging to Electronics major.

Comment: Looks like this question is best suited for quora. For EE.SE its off topic I guess.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with your life. If you want to learn electronics and make a career in it, definitely you can go ahead. It's never too late. Asking such questions in this forum won't help a lot because different person will have different opinion and no one will know what's best suited for you except yourself.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack I'm not seeking any career in Electronics, I just wanted to learn it to have a more knowledge about hardware design.

Comment: "Should I learn or it is for students belonging to Electronics major."    Why see this so black/white ? If this subject interests YOU then by all means, study it and go as far as YOU want to go. Consider this: if all FPGA designers have an EE background, what can YOU contribute with your CS background ? I think that could be a lot. Having an extra special skill/interest never hurts I would say.

Comment: There's no such thing as useless knowledge - learn anything and everything that interests you. Just the learning process trains you to learn better, no matter what the subject. If it doesn't compromise your known obligations, just do it.

Comment: As Peter Green effectively says "Everyone should learn about everything they can if it of interest, subject to the demands of more vital or even more interesting things". :-). Warning: Don't overdo it or you end up like me :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Overdo it ?? do you mean more than enough.

Comment: @Atinesh Yes !!! :-). I manage :-) [Google my name :-) ].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you find the area interesting I would encourage you to go ahead.

I don't think it will hurt to have an understanding of how hardware works and if you enjoy it you may even be able to make a career out of taking algorithms and turning them into synthisisable VHDL/verilog code.

Comment: The really great thing about FPGA's is that they can process certain data or do certain tasks orders of magnitude faster than your processors used in general CS. So you may well find that FPGA skill turns a very slow and unsatisfactory process/control problem in to a very fast and useful process/control solution. They are almost a solution looking for a problem... With luck you could be  wowing your final year project assessors . With bad luck you'll know what the hardware/firmware people are jabbering on about. So still a plus.